# Conceptual Requirement and Scope

Tags: requirements

Appreciate your help with my questions

- What are conceptual requirements? How do they compare with stakeholder, business and functional requirements?
- what CASE tools can be used to capture conceptual requirements and scope?

Answer (score 1):

You're running into some odd terminology.  A conceptual requirement is somewhat like a "Principles of Operation" or what we at Sun (RIP) used to call a "one pager".  The idea is to present a short (!!) document describing the problem, the desired solution, and the business case for doing it.

The ideal case tool for this is a plain text file, although Word or OpenOffice are certainly acceptable in a pinch.

Comment: +1, and I'd give you more if I could for saying that it has to be short and plain. It's the only way to truly show that you know why a thing should be done, and everything else stems from it or decorates it.